# Is there a method to convert a Metpy output to numpy variable

Tags: python, numpy, metpy

I calculated the wind direction using Metpy. How can I extract the values and use the values as input in another part of my program?

In the sample code below, I would like to display the direction as a numpy variable, so I can use it in my program.

```
import metpy.calc as mpcalc
import numpy as np

# Make some fake data for us to work with
np.random.seed(19990503)  # So we all have the same data
u = np.random.randint(0, 15, 10) * units('m/s')
v = np.random.randint(0, 15, 10) * units('m/s')
direction = mpcalc.wind_direction(u, v)
print(direction)
```

Comment: Does `np.array(direction)` not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a metpy result from a wind calculation to a numpy array, simply use the numpy `np.array` function.

```py
import metpy.calc as mpcalc
from metpy.units import units
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(19990503)
u = np.random.randint(0, 15, 10)*units("m/s")
v = np.random.randint(0, 15, 10)*units("m/s")
direction = mpcalc.wind_direction(u, v)
direction_numpy = np.array(direction)
```

Comment: **A heads up:** I noticed very wrong values when I tried this solution in the presence of NaN values. For me, numpy sometimes puts numbers instead of a NaN seemingly randomly. Meaning some NaN remain, others are replaced by numbers but the values are not obvious to me. For example: `[-- -- 27.964148473457783 --]` converts to `[        nan,         nan, 27.96414847, 81.71656571]`. In my case, [the solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76584767/9891955) works.

Comment: The `--` are part of the outputs that I get from `metpy.calc`, i.e. it must be how `pint.Quantity` represents missing values. Ah, I see, then it might be specific to my application. Maybe this could be added to the answer then so that other people dont run into the same issue?

Comment: I don't have metpy anymore to test it, but you might be able to preprocess the `--`s to ensure numpy converts them to nans.

Comment: Add what to the answer? The `--` issue?

Comment: Converting `--` beforehand would be an option. For my case, it makes more sense to use `magnitude` and keep NaNs though. I mean maybe add a note that this solution might not work well with NaNs. However, I am digging currently and for OPs question NaNs seem to not be a problem, however I was calculating `metpy.calc.apparent_temperature` and in this case, the conversion you propose doesn't work. So this might just be a corner case.

Answer (score 3):

Another option, which I would recommend would be to use the `.magnitude` attribute (or `.m` for short), which gives you the underlying data as appropriate (numpy array or xarray `DataArray`):

```py
import metpy.calc as mpcalc
import numpy as np

# Make some fake data for us to work with
np.random.seed(19990503)  # So we all have the same data
u = np.random.randint(0, 15, 10) * units('m/s')
v = np.random.randint(0, 15, 10) * units('m/s')
direction = mpcalc.wind_direction(u, v)
print(direction.magnitude)
```

You can also use `.m_as()` to convert to desired units before printing:

```py
print(direction.m_as('mph'))
```